# Does Gorilla/schema support the `json` reflection tag natively?

Tags: go, gorilla

In the documentation, [Gorilla/schema](https://github.com/gorilla/schema) says that you must specify the `schema` reflection tag to unpack the struct. I've seen it unpack when I don't have the schema tag, for example when I just am using the `json` tag.

When the `schema` tag isn't specified what does Gorilla do under the covers? Does it look at other tags or does it do a case-insensitive match? Is there a huge performance hit as a result of not specifying the `schema` tag?

EDIT: Specified/linked package

Comment: Update: The `gorilla/schema` library mentions the `json` tag in [three places](https://github.com/gorilla/schema/search?q=json&unscoped_q=json), all in tests.

Comment: The `schema` tag is not required, as inferred by their documentation (and indeed their initial example omits them). "To define custom names for fields, use a struct tag "schema"." http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema . Without specifying the tag, the field name is taken directly from the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others searching for this answer -

This package has the ability to use any tag. The default is `schema` ([which is initialized here](https://github.com/gorilla/schema/blob/master/cache.go#L22)). To change the tag it's searching for, use `decoder.SetAliasTag("json")`. While I think the fallback logic is [around this function](https://github.com/gorilla/schema/blob/master/cache.go#L155), I'm not totally certain what the performance hit really is from not explicitly setting a different tag.

Comment: That's actually a cool feature. As far as performance impact, there shouldn't be anything really. Here is the function you are looking for. https://github.com/gorilla/schema/blob/master/cache.go#L243

Comment: Actually, if you wanted to get right down to over-optimization (which is generally a bad thing), I'd say using the field name saves a minuscule number of operations. If the tag exists, it has to parse the string to get it and the options set, which does a `strings.Split`. Don't over-optimize because of this though... it's just a few cycles. Benefits of using a tag+options far outweigh any losses.